# Tailwindcss not working in some of components in React / Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I am working with Tailwindcss in my Next.js, and styling it. But Tailwind not working in some components in my project.

> Note: Components that not working TailwindCSS in them has been placed in : @/comps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add `comps` folder in your `tailwind.config.js` file, like this:

```
import type { Config } from 'tailwindcss'

const config: Config = {
  content: [
    './pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './comps/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
export default config
```